# Does Xamarin.forms picker accepts or adds string only or could we customize it to accept views or controls?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Does Xamarin.forms picker accepts or adds string only or could we customize it to accept views or controls? I have issue while creating dropdown with customize view like switch on leftside for each row in picker? But xamarin.forms picker doesnot give facility for customizing its view, it only accepts string as DisplayProperty. How can we implement this feature or any better alternatives for doing this, suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XF Picker accept only strings. To create a DropDown, you should create a popup page under your control.

I usually use [this plugin for popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)

It's very easy to use. You can create your contentpage and "popup" it. To have a dropdown, you have only to position the contentpage under your control.

```
// Use these methods in PopupNavigation globally or Navigation in your pages

// Open new PopupPage
Task PushAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.PushPopupAsync

// Hide last PopupPage
Task PopAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopPopupAsync

// Hide all PopupPage with animations
Task PopAllAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync

// Remove one popup page in stack
Task RemovePageAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.RemovePopupPageAsync


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             x:Class="Demo.Pages.MyPopupPage">
  <!--Animations use example-->
  <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <animations:ScaleAnimation 
      PositionIn="Center"
      PositionOut="Center"
      ScaleIn="1.2"
      ScaleOut="0.8"
      DurationIn="400"
      DurationOut="300"
      EasingIn="SinOut"
      EasingOut="SinIn"
      HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
  </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
  <!-- Content -->
</pages:PopupPage>
```

Comment: I have successfully created popUpPage, but my problem is i have to put that popup page in between another contentpage, where i have got xaml error like----> expected view but got usercontrol. I have made <pages:PopupPage> as parent. How to resolve this issue? How to place popup in between other page.

Comment: You have not to place popup "between" other page, but "over" other page. try to set WidthRequest and HeightRequest's PopUpPage so you should have a transparent zone around your PopUp

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion, i am able to customise as per my needs with your ideas. Happy Coding !!!